# WebRTC Audio Processing Module (APM) and calculating echo delay for a playback device

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing, webrtc, aec

I am very new to audio processing. I created a program that records and streams audio *one way*, and does not record on the other end. Basically, it transmit whatever is recorded in one location to another location. However, there are many circumstances where this program will also output the audio in the same location as the recording source. This creates a noticeable "echo" because of the audio delay (which is dependent on many factors).

Because I'm not sure if anything else is out there, I am trying to use WebRTC's audio processing module for Gain Control and acoustic echo cancellation. The gain control seems to work well, but the AEC doesn't really work so well. I'm assuming maybe it's because I am not setting the correct stream delay, or maybe this isn't really what AEC is for.

The current code that I'm using reads something I've recorded from a file in an attempt to get rid of the echo, at least the first occurrence of it. If I set the stream delay to 0. as we can imagine the current audio gets cancelled out completely. I try different values to not much avail.

So my question is, and I hope this is specific enough, what am I doing wrong in this model here?

```
void start( char *inFilename, char *outFilename )
{
    FILE *infile = fopen( inFilename, "rb" );
    FILE *outfile = fopen( outFilename, "wb" );

    // Our frame manager
    AudioFrame frame;
    frame._audioChannel = CHANNELS;
    frame._frequencyInHz = SAMPLERATE;
    frame._payloadDataLengthInSamples = SAMPLERATE/100; // Math for 20ms frames

    // Get the size of our frames
    const size_t frameLength = frame._payloadDataLengthInSamples*CHANNELS;


    AudioProcessing* apm = AudioProcessing::Create(0);
    //
    apm->set_sample_rate_hz( SAMPLERATE ); // Super-wideband processing.
    //
    // // Mono capture and stereo render.
    apm->set_num_channels(1, 1);
    apm->set_num_reverse_channels(1);
    //
    apm->high_pass_filter()->Enable(true);
    //
    //apm->echo_cancellation()->set_suppression_level( EchoCancellation::SuppressionLevel::kHighSuppression );
    apm->echo_cancellation()->enable_drift_compensation( false );
    apm->echo_cancellation()->Enable( true );
    //
    apm->noise_suppression()->set_level( NoiseSuppression::Level::kHigh );
    apm->noise_suppression()->Enable( true );
    //
    apm->gain_control()->set_analog_level_limits( 0, 255 );
    apm->gain_control()->set_mode( GainControl::Mode::kAdaptiveDigital );
    apm->gain_control()->Enable( true );
    //
    // apm->voice_detection()->Enable(true);
    //
    // // Start a voice call...

    while( fread(frame._payloadData, sizeof( int16_t ), frameLength, infile )==frameLength )
    {
        //apm->set_stream_delay_ms( 0 );

        apm->AnalyzeReverseStream( &frame );
        //
        // // ... Render frame arrives bound for the audio HAL ...
        //
        // // ... Capture frame arrives from the audio HAL ...
        // // Call required set_stream_ functions.
        // apm->gain_control()->set_stream_analog_level(analog_level);
        //

        apm->set_stream_delay_ms( 300 );

        int err = apm->ProcessStream( &frame );

        fprintf( stdout, "Output %i\n", err );
        //
        // // Call required stream_ functions.
        // analog_level = apm->gain_control()->stream_analog_level();
        // has_voice = apm->stream_has_voice();


        fwrite( frame._payloadData, sizeof( int16_t ), frameLength, outfile );
    }

    //
    // // Repeate render and capture processing for the duration of the call...
    // // Start a new call...
    // apm->Initialize();
    //
    // // Close the application...
    AudioProcessing::Destroy( apm );
    apm = NULL;

    fclose( infile );
    fclose( outfile );
}
```

Using the includes and libraries from: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/webrtc-audio-processing/

Comment: Here is an example that will explain a lot about WebRtc Audio Processing with a working example: https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC

Comment: @MuhammadUsman disclaimer you are also the author?

Comment: I'm not an auther of WebRTC. I've more than 1 year of research & workaround on WebRTC Native Modules i.e. ( Signaling, Audio Processing ) And I know how best and possibly, I can manipulate different WebRTC modules.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem to , i have try to find API that tells me how much stream delay is in OpenSLES API manual but failed.
As now, i think it maybe need to calculate stream delay by myself.